# Connect to Amazon Cloud with FTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftps

I'm looking to develop a web app which will be using Amazon cloud, but its dependant on the need for a 3rd party being able to deploy data files to Amazon through FTPS. 
The 3rd party only uses FTPS and not ftp or sftp. Is connecting to Amazon Cloud possible using FTPS?

Comment: You would just deploy an EC2 instance running whatever FTPS server you want, and give the third party the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I'm only familiar with amazons cloud storage solutions and looking for a way Cloud service I can run a php framework based app, but the requirement is that I can have this third party which only uses ftps be able to send me data dumps. I'll investigate ec2 further.

Answer (score 1):

"Amazon Cloud" is a very broad term. I suggest you spend a little time looking into all the different services offered by Amazon Web Services. One of those services is the Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) that you can use to spin up instances of virtual Linux and Windows servers. You can install any services on those servers you want, including an FTPS service.

Comment: Thanks mark, I'll definitely have a look at ec2. There are so many Amazon services that its tough to figure what I need. Thanks for the pointer though, helps to narrow things down.